# asp.net identity 3 does not support async for List of Roles

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I have the following code

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

private async Task DoStuff(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    var roles =  await _roleManager.Roles;
    var mylist = await _myRepository.SelectAll();
}
```

however the only method the  role manager support is

```
public virtual IQueryable<TRole> Roles { get; }
```

and not an async method.

Github [reference](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/89a9acea96d2cdd8d4c1e57e8356959114bc7eb6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/RoleManager.cs)

resulting in only a `_roleManager.Roles.ToList()` method and not a `ToListAsync()`

so I'm forced to change my code to

```
 var roles =  _roleManager.Roles;
```

however now it doesn't wait anymore and will cause unexpected behaviour since the method itself is asynchronous.

Question:

Is there anyway I can still use an asynchronous method for the above

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known async method is not supported to fetch all the roles via the rolemanager.

You can solve it by accessing the roles via the databasecontext:

```
var roles = await this._context.Roles.ToListAsync();
```